# Why I cannot set a title of my UINavigationController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UINavigationController` in my app and I added there the segmented control:

[image]

I also have a button and when user presses it, I want to hide the segmented control and display a string instead.

I can hide the segmented control by doing:

```
segmentedControl.hidden = true
```

and it works, but when I write in the code:

```
self.title = "test"
```

then the test word does not appear. What's the problem here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already set `titleView` of `navigationItem` and trying to set `title` then you need to first set `titleView` as `nil` then only it will display your title on `NavigationBar`.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
self.navigationItem.title = "Test"
```

**Edit:** To get the instance of `SegmentedControl` back you need to first store  the instance from `titleView` like this.

```
self.segmentedControl = self.navigationItem.titleView as! UISegmentedControl
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIView() //Set blank view so it will not nil the object of SegmentedControl
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
self.navigationItem.title = "Test"
```

Comment: can you tell me how to come back to the segmentedControl displayed there? I tried with `self.navigationItem.titleView = mySegmentedControl` but it didn't show up and the `test` word is still visible...

Comment: For that you need to store instance of segmentedcontrol before setting it to nil.

Comment: hm can you give me some bigger insight in it? it sounds reasonable, but I don't know how to do it in Swift :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use

```
self.navigationItem.title = "test"
```

I just made a test case and it worked for me.